# How to architect a extendable component based Web application?

Tags: javascript, components, encapsulation, shadow-dom

I am trying to architect an extendable Web applications that allows users to build and export static websites. Similar to [this site](http://www.layoutit.com/build) and [this site](https://scripteden.com/builder/bootstrap/), except developers can build their own custom components using HTML,CSS and Javascript and add it to the public library.

The Architecture must:

1. Ensure that user added components can not interfere with each other (Encapsulation)

   - HTML attributes have unique values (`<div id="a">` remains unique to this component)
   - CSS is namespaced
   - Javascript objects are scoped and can only modify DOM elements within this component.
2. Enable developers  to build components in simple HTML, CSS, Javascript without the need for building a React/Vue/Angular etc. JS components.
3. Developers can build components without worrying about encapsulation issues above. i.e. The application transforms the unsafe HTML,CSS,Javascript to one which is safe.
4. Ensures cross-browser compatibility

iFrames provide excellent encapsulation but have performance and device scaling issues. I have been reading about Shadow DOM, Web components but haven't been able to figure out the correct approach to build such a Web Application.

I also came across this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768104/how-to-create-a-flexible-plug-in-architecture) but it seems like this is more geared toward back-end. Please correct me if I am wrong. Is there any existing framework/build tools/library that I can use? If not how should I go about building such a tool?