# How platforms enable custom plugins

Tags: architecture, system, system-design

I have a curiosity question that I cannot find any articles or blogs on. I am curious how some SASS platforms have built the ability for clients to create "plugins" that extend their platforms capability. For instance, like shopify.

If you know of any resources that I can read up on designs and/or system architectures, please comment them below!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins are enabled by mainly two things:

1. An Interface/API that is designed to communicate with the platform for all pluggable behaviors. Most often done via a scripting language interface, such as Javascript or Python. The API will often allow for calling to manipulate the platform in some ways as well as a form of event registration in order to execute the plugin code on specific platform events, e.g. "customer registered event" or "invoice sent event".
2. A form of plugin registration and execution. Often via configuration files or conventions, such as plugin folder locations, specific interfaces, upload functionality etc.

Security is always an important topic when designing a plugin interface. Some platforms will define their own domain specific language for plugins that is more restricted than a generic scripting language. Others will only provide a limited set of libraries that can be used.

I also recommend to check [this Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768104/how-to-create-a-flexible-plug-in-architecture) and this [openstack article](https://docs.openstack.org/stevedore/latest/user/essays/pycon2013.html) describes the plugin-design-pattern with an example.