# plugin base pattern for web app

Tags: java, design-patterns

I would like in a web application to be able to add some functionnality

Is there any pattern for a web application to be able to add plugin?
Every plugins could be a jar file and the user could select the plugin it want to use.
Does somebody have information about this kind of action?

Comment: i found some usefull information in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613935/java-plugin-framework-choice